# xhr.response Text is returning Object Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working with an API that gives out articles, in the array there are attributes such as author, title, description.  Each time I try I only get back Object Object.

I've tried doing innerHTML, consolelog and now Im trying p.textContent, which at least is accessing and entering data, just not grabbing the data I need.

```
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // Only run if the request is complete
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
    // Process our return data
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        // This will run when the request is successful
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      var body = document.querySelector('.loadNews');
      // Create paragraph element
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      // Update content of p element with API data
      p.textContent = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      // Append p element to body
      body.appendChild(p);
```

what results is I get Object Object instead of the actual data that i'm trying to use.

Comment: console.log use and paste output there

Comment: You have this line, `data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` but it doesn't look like you use the variable. Based on your code it appears to be in json format but you are treating it as html.

Answer (score 0):

If the input to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is an object string, it will return an object, and if you try to print that return value as a string, you will get `[object Object]`. Instead, you should be trying to access the properties of the object e.g.

```
data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
p.textcontent = 'author: ' + data.author;
```